# How to assign a Contribution to a different contact or otherwise have the receipt go to a different contact

Tags: civicontribute, receipts

A contribution is made by Contact A, but they require the receipt to go to Contact B. What other option is there other than deleting the Contribution record and creating a new one for Contact B.

I have re-read about Soft Credit but see nothing that offers this functionality.

With access to the DB we can update the record (and associated Activities) directly but not ideal.

Is there any 'transfer Contribution' type feature or extension anyone has come across? There was an "I am making one" comment [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=22870.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time after the question was asked ... but see https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution

Comment: Anyone know whether this works with CiviCRM 5.x? In particular we are running 5.10.3 and about to update to 5.13.5